# ODE $y(x)=xy'(x)-\sqrt{y'(x)-1}$

Tags: integration, ordinary-differential-equations, derivatives

I've following differential equation...

$$y(x)=xy'(x)-\sqrt{y'(x)-1}$$

I recognised that it's an Clairaut's equation and then I wanted to find the general and the singular solution.

First I reformed the ODE like that...

$$\frac{d}{dx}y=\frac{d}{dx}dy'-\frac{d}{dx}\sqrt{y'-1}$$
$$y'=xy''+y'-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y'-1}}*y''$$
$$0=y''(x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y'-1}})$$

I can then deduce, that the equation is true if

1. $y''=0$ or
2. $x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y'-1}}=0$

I solved 1) like that...

$$\int y'' dx = 0 \Leftrightarrow y'=C$$

In our original equation, that gives us...

$$y=Cx-\sqrt{C-1}$$

Then I solved 2)

$$x-\frac{1}{2\sqrt{y'-1}}=0 \Leftrightarrow y'=\frac{1}{4x^2}+1$$
$$\int y'\, dx=\int \frac{1}{4x^2}+1 \, dx$$
$$y = -\frac{1}{2x}+x+C$$

But I've drawn graphs of these two equations and 1), aka the general solution, doesn't touch 2), aka the singular solution.

So i probably have a mistake somewhere, don't I? Can someone point it out to me?

Comment: why did the factor 4 disapear in the last equation ? You should have $-\dfrac 1 {4x}$

Comment: True that. Sometimes I make super simple mistakes.

Comment: No problem Quotenbanane

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can insert the expressions
$$
\sqrt{y'-1}=\frac1{2x}
$$
and
$$
y'=\frac1{4x^2}+1
$$
directly into the original equation to get
$$
y=\frac1{4x}+x-\frac1{2x}=x-\frac1{4x}
$$
This is the only singular solution.

You have a constant error in integrating $\frac1{4x^2}$, and you did not compare with the original equation to get $C=0$ in the singular solution.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Is the C always 0 by default or do I always have to check? Cause I did some more examples and till now C was always 0.

Comment: No, the constant may depend on the path you take towards the integration (not really in this case). It may happen that different substitutions give anti-derivatives that differ by a constant. But you can always insert the expression for $y'$ from $0=x+f'(y')$ into the original equation without any further integration.